# Spring бесконечный redirect

Tags: java, spring, redirect

Использую **Spring Boot**, когда пользователь заходит на любой ресурс `/web/**` его редиректило на страницу `/web/index.html`, т.е. если он пытается зайти на `/web/213.html`, его редиректило на `/web/index.html` и так же с другими ссылками.

Для этого я написал

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter forwardToIndex(){
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry){
                registry.addViewController("/web/**").setViewName("redirect:/web/index.html");
            }
        };
    }
```

но если использовать это, то получается бесконечный редирект на `index.html`, т.к. `index.html` лежит в папке web.

Как мне сделать редирект только один раз?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Самый простой и очевидный путь - вынести `index.html` из папки `web`. Если по каким-либо причинам этот путь вам не подходит, можно использовать такой workaround:

```
registry
    .addViewController("/web/{page:(?!index\\.html).+}")
    .setViewName("redirect:/web/index.html");
```

Используемый по умолчанию `PathMatcher` ([`AntPathMatcher`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html)) не поддерживает сравнение URL по регулярным выражениям, зато поддерживает регулярные выражения в `PathVariable`. Этим мы и воспользуемся: в URL добавляем переменную `page` с ограничением возможных значений по регулярному выражению. Если вам незнакома конструкция вида `(?!index\.html).+` - это регулярное выражение с [негативной опережающей проверкой](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.93.D1.80.D1.83.D0.BF.D0.BF.D1.8B) (negative lookahead, взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/977294/4863012)). Под него подходят любые строки, кроме `index.html` ([demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qb6RWCjLHWdEPBkY)). В результате мы получаем redirect, срабатывающий на любые URL, кроме `/web/index.html`.